# Error after build App :ag-grid with Angular 6

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid with angular 6 so for everything works just fine but when i build my app with `ng build` it build successfully but when i run my app
i got this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'AG_GRID' of undefined at ComponentProvider.push.../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/components/framework/componentProvider.js.ComponentProvider.retrieve (main.cd682685b0beea93bbaf.js:48587)
    at ComponentResolver.push.../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/components/framework/componentResolver.js.ComponentResolver.resolveByName (main.cd682685b0beea93bbaf.js:48969)
    at ComponentResolver.push.../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/components/framework/componentResolver.js.ComponentResolver.getComponentToUse (main.cd682685b0beea93bbaf.js:48965)
    at ComponentResolver.push.../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/components/framework/componentResolver.js.ComponentResolver.newAgGridComponent (main.cd682685b0beea93bbaf.js:49087)
    at ComponentResolver.push.../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/components/framework/componentResolver.js.ComponentResolver.createAgGridComponent (main.cd682685b0beea93bbaf.js:49050)
    at ComponentRecipes.push.../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/components/framework/componentRecipes.js.ComponentRecipes.newLoadingOverlayComponent (main.cd682685b0beea93bbaf.js:48740)
    at OverlayWrapperComponent.push.../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/overlays/overlayWrapperComponent.js.OverlayWrapperComponent.showLoadingOverlay (main.cd682685b0beea93bbaf.js:68183)
    at BorderLayout.push.../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/layout/borderLayout.js.BorderLayout.showLoadingOverlay (main.cd682685b0beea93bbaf.js:63585)
    at GridPanel.push.../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/gridPanel/gridPanel.js.GridPanel.showLoadingOverlay (main.cd682685b0beea93bbaf.js:58572)
    at GridPanel.push.../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/gridPanel/gridPanel.js.GridPanel.init (main.cd682685b0beea93bbaf.js:57948)
```

Comment: Do you have `AgGridModule.withComponents(array_of_custom_ag_grid_components_),` in the imports of the module that uses ag-grid?

Answer (score 0):

You have a [runtime error](https://techterms.com/definition/runtime_error). The error message suggests, that there is an object, which *should have* a property (AG_GRID) but instead, it is valued `undefined`, therefore there is no "undefined.AG_GRID" so it throws a TypeError.

Also, as the problem is not in your code but in your dependencies (`node_modules` folder), it is strongyl possible, that there are some problems with the versions of your dependencies.

try to:

- delete node_modules folder
- run ng update --all
- run npm install
- try ng serve to debug locally

If the package is outdated, you might need to go back a few versions, or remove it from your project, until it is fixed or updated. Check the official repository of the project, as there are [similar issues there](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2148): so it is possible that you cannot use the tool with angular 6 just yet.

Comment: when i run locally with ng serve it works but with ng build i got the error message

Comment: what version of ag-grid do you use? can you post your package.json?

Comment: I'm using latest version  :"ag-grid": "^17.1.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^17.1.0",

Comment: @balteo yes it seems that it is @angular/cli probleme